# which one is the most appropriate sentence?

Tags: american-english

I am curious about which sentence are correct?

1. "I mean that how can I know, which REMAP[0] is used for"

2. "I mean, how can I find out what REMAP[0] is used for?"

What if 2 is then why?
What if 1 is to be correct sentence what it need to?

Comment: Please expand your question. It's not very clear what are you asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing, because your two sentences have *several* differences.

Since I do not know what REMAP[0] is, I will replace it with *a hammer*. It doesn't change your sentence structure, but it makes it a bit easier to follow for those who do not know about REMAP[0].

Lets go at it step by step. What is it that you want to know? You want to know **what** a hammer is used for.
*Which* a hammer is used for makes little sense: *which* would make sense if I have three hammers, and I am wondering *which one* to use:

> I am wondering *which hammer* to use for this.

So, we stick with **what** (it is used for), and for now we replace that with *something*.

In your sentences, *know* and *find out* are grammatically interchangeable. Which one you want to use is up to you, and it depends on what you want to say. I will get back to it later, but for now I will use _find out in booth sentences.
So, your sentences are simplified to:

> I mean that how can I find out something.
>   I mean, how can I find out something?

Now it gets tricky...
*I mean that [something]* is perfectly fine as a construction, but it is actually very difficult to put a *question* into that *something*.
These sentences are absolutely fine:

> I mean that [I want to find out how to use a hammer].
>   I mean that [I know how to use a hammer].

After *that*, we do not change the order of subject and verb in our sentence. However, after *how*, we do! And you did that correctly:

> *I can* find out how to use a hammer => How *can I* find out how to use a hammer?

It feels unnatural to use *that* (normal order) and *how* (reversed order) together in a sentence, because now we do not know whether to reverse *I can* or not.

By simply replacing *that* with a comma, this problem is gone. If we start our sentence with *“I mean,”* , we can follow with a normal statement, or a question, _just as if the *I mean* wasn't there! (You could actually also use a *colon* in the same way.)

Both these sentences are correct:

> I mean, I know what a hammer is used for.
>   I mean, how should I know what a hammer is used for?

The one remaining question is, whether we should use *know* of *find out*. Well, that depends, like I said, on what you want to say.

If you want to say “I don't know what a hammer is used for, and I mean to ask you how I can find out”, then you use *find out*. *Find out* is used if you mean to *learn* something. I actually assume that this is the sentence as you meant to form it:

> **I mean, how can I find out what a hammer is used for?**

On the other hand, if somebody assumes that you know what a hammer is used for, but you don't, you might want to ask them why they assume you know that. How could you? They know you have never seen or used a hammer, so how can they assume that you know what it's for?

> I mean, how do I know what a hammer is used for?
>   I mean, how could I know what a hammer is used for?
>   I mean, how should I know what a hammer is used for?

All three sentences are *rhetorical* questions: you do not really expect an answer, you are basically making a statement. To exemplify the difference between *do*, *could* and *should* I will paraphrase the *statements* you make in these three “questions”:

> I do not know what a hammer is used for.
>   I could not possible know what a hammer is used for.
>   I should not be expected to know what a hammer is used for.

**Note** that I included the *do* version only for completeness. Of the three options, I feel it is the least natural. 
It is important to understand that *know* is about describing a state of knowing something, not about *learning* something:

> How can I know this? <= _this does **not** mean “how can I learn this?”
>   *it means:* How can you assume that I know this? You are so wrong!

Comment: In your answer, I am still not sure about this. How can I know this? <= _this does not mean “how can I learn this?”
it means: How can you assume that I know this? You are so wrong! Would you please let me know the nuance between them?